llvm-objdump equivalent of aarch64-none-linux-gnu-objdump
Suppose I put four bytes into a file and then disassemble it using the GNU toolchain:
-bash$ echo -en '\x1f\x20\x03\xd5' > ./myFile
-bash$ aarch64-none-linux-gnu-objdump -m AARCH64 -b binary -D ./myFile

./myFile:     file format binary

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000000 <.data>:
   0:   d503201f    nop

Note that myFile is not a proper ELF file or an object file, yet I can still disassemble it!
How can I do something similar with llvm-objdump?
-bash$ llvm-objdump --arch=arm64 -D x
.../llvm-16.0.4/bin/llvm-objdump: error: 'x': The file was not recognized as a valid object file

Is there a mechanism to do what I want using ARM's armclang, armasm, or fromelf?

Figured it out.  The key is to use objcopy to turn the raw binary data into an ELF.  Then LLVM's objdump can disassemble it...
-bash$ echo -en '\x1f\x20\x03\xd5' > ./myFile
-bash$ /path/to/llvm-16.0.4/bin/llvm-objcopy \
         -I binary \
         -O elf64-littleaarch64 \
         --rename-section=.data=.text,code \
         ./myFile \
         ./myFile.elf
-bash$ /path/to/llvm-16.0.4/bin/llvm-objdump \
         --arch=arm64 \
         --disassemble \
         ./myFile.elf

myFile.elf: file format elf64-littleaarch64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_binary___myFile_start>:
       0: d503201f      nop

I'm still interested in how to do this with the ARM toolchain "ARM Compiler for Embedded" aka armclang.  They don't supply objdump or objcopy.
